# Windows 10 reagentc.exe file is missing

Tags: windows-10-universal

**The story**: I purchased an open box MSI WT73VR and the previous owner still has their windows user account that is required to login. No big deal. All I need to do is do a factory restore. So I reboot and press F3 which takes me to the recovery options screen. I select factory restore and I get the error, "REagentc.exe not found. Try again later". I then open a command prompt and confirm that reagentc.exe is missing from the X drive by running a dir reagentc.exe /s /p which returned no matches.

**The questions**: Can I download reagentc.exe from Microsoft to a USB drive and copy it to X:\wnidows\system32 ? Is there a better way to get a factory restore for this computer? I read an article that said if I create a Microsoft 10 boot cd from their website it will permanently break a lot of msi features such as the F3 key.